# linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation - swift 4

Tags: swift, xcode

I have changed the project's name and it was running fine
I installed new pod and changed the target name and there was no problem too 
then suddenly I found that error, I uninstalled the pod and couldn't get rid of this error

Comment: Is there anything else in the logs that you can upload? There's not enough info to diagnose your problem.

Comment: I found this error while building
linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: when you change your app name (target) you have to delete POD folder, podlock file, and workspace file. Then change target name on Podfile before reinstall pods.